# Linear integral with 2 points in space

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$ \int_{AB}  yz dx + zx dy + xy dz $

This is my line integral and I need to find out a method to solve it. I have 2 points A(1,1,0) and B(2,3,1). These 2 points form a line in space.
What I find hard to comprehend is that I have to apply this theory:

$ \frac {\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} $

$ \frac {\partial Q}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial y} $

$ \frac{\partial R}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial z} $

What do these partial derivatives represent? Functions?

Besides that,there is another formula shown below that represent 3 integrals. These 3 integrals represent a function in space? If so,what does the variable $t$ means? A constant?

$V(x,y,z)= \int_{x_0}^{x} P(t,y_0,z_0) dt+\int_{y_0}^{y} Q(x,t,z_0)dt+\int_{z_0}^{z}R(x,y,t)dt$

Can someone explain each part to me? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Anyone? I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\int_C P \, dx + Q \, dy + R \, dz$ is also sometimes written as $\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r}$, where $\vec{F} = \left< P,Q,R \right>$, so $P,Q,R$ are the components of the vector field. In your example, $P = yz$, $Q = zx$, and $R = xy$.

The equations you wrote with the partial derivatives are another way of saying that the "curl" of this vector field is zero. In math notation, $\nabla \times \vec{F} = \vec{0}$. I assume you've seen curl before? This means the vector field is "*conservative*".

When a vector field is conservative, it means there is a "*potential function*" $f(x,y,z)$, so that $\vec{F}$ is its gradient. In other words, $\vec{F} = \nabla f$.

The **Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals** says that the value of this line integral is the difference of the values of the potential function at the endpoints:
$$ \int_{AB} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r} = f(B) - f(A) $$

So if you can find this potential function $f$ (I hope you can  do that yourself, it's really quite easy in this example), then you don't need to do the integral at all! You just plug the points $A$ and $B$ into this function and subtract.

Comment: Do you mean something like this V(x,y,z)=(z,x,y) ?

Comment: Is $V$ the potential function? If so, then $V(x,y,z) = xyz$. This is what I was calling $f$ in my answer.

Comment: You have been given an excellent answer by Nick. I just upvoted it, and you should  at least upvote it (it is a manner to say "thank you"), but even validate it : you will definitely not receive better answers to this question.